# No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA resize Select Images Window

Tags: javascript, css, recaptcha

it is possible to resize the Images select window on reCaptcha?
In my PopUp (h:490/w:650) the the pictures are cut off.. here an example:
[image]
Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Tough without seeing the code, but you could probably add some styles to your stylesheet that make the images smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Clicking 'I am not a robot' Expand the window as large as you can to allow room for the images and other elements to grow. I have found this to work with a site that user Recaptcha.